# "code": -2014, "msg": "API-key format invalid." -- Binance API

Tags: python, binance-api-client, python-binance

I don't know how to solve this problem. I can run the code successfully, but the result is an empty Dataframe. On the webpage, the error is
{
"code": -2014,
"msg": "API-key format invalid."
}

## code

'''

```
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)

base_url = "https://api.binance.com"
api_path = "/sapi/v1/margin/allOrders"
timestamp = int(time.time()*1000)
limit = 500
timestamp = int(time.time()*1000)
end_time = int(time.time()//60*60*1000)
start_time = int(end_time-limit*60*1000)
API_KEY = 'my_api_key'
params = {
    'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
    'startTime': str(start_time),
    'endTime': str(end_time),
    'timestamp': timestamp
}

headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': API_KEY
}

url = base_url+api_path

while True:

    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, params = params, headers = headers)
    data=response.json()
    df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns={'clientOrderId':0, 'cummulativeQuoteQty':1, 'executedQty':2, 
                              'icebergQty':3, 'isWorking':4, 'orderId':5, 'origQty':6, 
                              'quoteQty':7, 'side':9,'status':10, 'stopPrice':11,
                              'symbol':12, 'isIsolated':13, 'time':14,
                              'timeInForce':15, 'type':16, 'selfTradePreventionMode':17, 
                              'updateTime':18})
    df.set_index('symbol', inplace= True)
    df.to_csv(("Query Margin Account's All Orders_1") + '.csv')
    print(df)

    if len(df)< 500:
        break
        end_time = start_time
        start_time = int(end_time - limit *60 * 1000)
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you certain you have the API Key in the right format?

Comment: sure,  like this 'RWrTEgj7Wx4osRBtKLqpd262ZZK965JIX1GAj7mdyQEojNhJIY0ooTdAfcO2HGMO'. (this  is an example)

Comment: No, I didn't mean to *tell* me what the API key is.   I'm just asking if it's the right format..   Now that you've posted it, please *regenerate* a new key.

Comment: No problem. It is just an example. Sorry, I don't understand what is the right format of API key.

Comment: Also while scanning the information, I noticed it also mentioned an api_secret key

Comment: Maybe you should try using https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python instead.

Comment: I don't mention an api_secret key in the code

Comment: I use the link u post to me,and i use the code in examples->margin->margin_account.py. After I enter the api key and secret key, it shows me error,

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm_Code\binance-connector-python-3.3.1\examples\spot\margin\margin_account.py", line 9, in <module>
    api_key, api_secret = get_api_key()
  File "D:\PyCharm_Code\binance-connector-python-3.3.1\examples\utils\prepare_env.py", line 14, in get_api_key
    return config["keys"]["api_key"], config["keys"]["api_secret"]
  File "C:\Users\glt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'keys'

Comment: Please include that in your post, not in the comments.

Comment: sorry, it was the first time to post on the stack overflow, I don't master of posting.

Comment: To run example, you should create a `config.ini` file with format from this example file https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python/blob/master/examples/config.ini.example, then you should be good to run all example files.